# Django modal content

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, bootstrap-modal

I have a weird problem with Bootstrap 4 modals and Django.

My website is supposed to display the modal to edit the address and return to the previous page after editing. For this purpose, I pass 2 parameters in the URL address.

When both parameters are given instead of modal to edit the address, the entire page is loaded.

This is my view:

```
class AddresssUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Address
    template_name = 'Order_app/address_form.html'
    form_class = AddressForm

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('Order_app:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

This is my modal content (address_form.html):

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
    {% if address %}
        <form role="form" action="{% url 'Order_app:edit_address' pk address_id %}" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Edit</h3>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="modal-body">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Save">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return hide_modal()">
                exit
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my urls.py file:

```
url(r'^$', views.ZleceniaListView.as_view(), name='lista_zlecen'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', views.OrderDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/(?P<adres_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.AddressUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit_address'),
```

My home page template fragment:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                            onclick="return abrir_modal('{% url 'Order_app:edit_address' order.pk address.pk %}')"
                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">
                        edit
</button>

<div class="modal" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div>


<script>
    function abrir_modal(url) {

        $('#Modal').load(url, function () {
            $(this).modal('show');
        });
        return false;
    }

    function hide_modal() {
        $('#Modal').modal('hide');
        return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#tab').dataTable({});
    });
</script>
```

If I try to pass one parameter, `addressid_is`, the modal is loading the right content, but then I can't go back to the previous page.

Comment: `if adres` Is this an intentional (mis)spelling?

Comment: Yes, but I fixed it now